# Finding sum of User Inputed Values

Tags: c++

I need help adding up several user inputed values using C++

```
double total;     // Accumulates total
double price;      // Gets next price from user
int numItems;     // Number of items
int counter = 1;  // Loop control counter

cout << "How many items do you have? ";
cin >> numItems;
cout << endl;

while (counter <= numItems) {
    total = 0;
    cout << "Enter the price of item " << counter << ": ";
    cin >> price;
    cout << endl;
    total += price;
    counter++;
}
cout << "The total price is: " << total << endl;
```

When I run my code, I end up getting the sum of only one value from the user

Comment: `total = 0;` should be before while loop..

Comment: wow, such an easy fix! thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just as Chetan Ranpariya said:

`total = 0;` should be before while loop.